# How do I make sure all of my values are computed in my loop?

Tags: python, loops, class, object

I am working on a 'keep the change assignment' where I round the purchases to the whole dollar and add the change to the savings account. However, the loop is not going through all of the values in my external text file. It only computes the last value. I tried splitting the file but it gives me an error. What might be the issue? my external text file is as so:

10.90
13.59
12.99 
(each on different lines)

def main():

```
account1 = BankAccount()                  
file1 = open("data.txt","r+")       # reading the file, + indicated read and write
s = 0       # to keep track of the new savings
for n in file1:
    n = float(n)    #lets python know that the values are floats and not a string
    z= math.ceil(n)      #rounds up to the whole digit
    amount = float(z-n)         # subtract the rounded sum with actaul total to get change
    print(" Saved $",round(amount,2), "on this purchase",file = file1)
    s = amount + s
    x = (account1.makeSavings(s))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure the reason for this is because you are printing the amount of money you have saved to the file. In general, you don't want to alter the length of an object you are iterating over because it can cause problems.

```
account1 = BankAccount()                  
file1 = open("data.txt","r+")       # reading the file, + indicated read and write
s = 0       # to keep track of the new savings
amount_saved = []
for n in file1:
    n = float(n)    #lets python know that the values are floats and not a string
    z= math.ceil(n)      #rounds up to the whole digit
    amount = float(z-n)         # subtract the rounded sum with actaul total to get change
    amount_saved.append(round(amount,2))
    s = amount + s
    x = (account1.makeSavings(s))
for n in amount_saved:
    print(" Saved $",round(amount,2), "on this purchase",file = file1)
```

This will print the amounts you have saved at the end of the file after you are finished iterating through it.